# IMG tag shows image in HTML but not in PHP

Tags: php, html, image

im making a php ebooksotre thing for my lass and i want to put an image but when i try it don't show up i run the file that have

```
<?php<div id="logo">
<img alt="logo" src="../images/logo.gif"
style="width: 200px; height:100px;" /> <h4>My e-Book Store</h4></div>
?>
```

It works like an HTML thing but when i put this code into main php file

```
 <?php require_once('lib/bookstoreimg.php'); ?>
```

It show's a small thing(like when you type wrong name/ file dont exists)
i tried 'bloginfo ('template_url'); and that does crazy things my container page and footer page disappears show exactly nothing not even the other thing not even the h4 tag (it was showing before) if you want i can send you my whole index.php so you can figure out what is going on exactly but i dont think something else affecting it ....
 **UPDATE:**  i was trying to find out how to show code

Comment: `if you want i can send you my whole index.php` .. What are you waiting for. Send it dude. :D :)

Comment: php won't display an image.  You can use it to generate the HTML that will show an image.  But by itself, it won't do anything.  It's entirely server side, meaning that the client only gets the result.

Comment: How do you expect us to help identify the problem if you don't show *any* code which demonstrates the problem?  You know we can't see your screen from here, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php <-- reading this will help you help yourself as well as help us help you.

Comment: Everything in your example should not be enclosed in php tags. That's HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'echo' command to print anything on screen.
To print your image on screen use:

```
<?php
echo'<div id="logo"><img alt="logo" src="../images/logo.gif" style="width: 200px; height:100px;" /> <h4>My e-Book Store</h4></div>'; ?>
```

PHP is made to dynamically show content. For example showing date.
You can read more about PHP here: http://php.net/docs.php

Comment: I just putted <?php ... ?> in the first code to post it i couldnt find ou out else how to show only html code sorry there is only div tag and img tag nothing else

Comment: Well, than you need to use include instead of require.

Comment: Same thing i tried it now it shows exactly the same